# drawing a line over a tabpage

Tags: c#, draw, picturebox, tabpage

edit:

I managed to add a [picturebox](https://i.hizliresim.com/qbLjMW.png) but I have no idea about how I can draw a line on it.

```
private void buttonDraw_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
pictureBoxDraw.BackColor = Color.Black;
pictureBoxDraw.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;

Graphics g = e.Graphics // I don't know this method.. I just need to draw a line here..
}
```

Comment: Number 23 today. Never do this: _System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();_.  Winforms graphics basic rule #1 : 

Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! (also never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or) draw  in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

Comment: And, of course you chose the wrong control (ie the form) for the wrong way to do it. This usually will not result in a positive result..  - -Note: Nested control sit above anything you draw onto their parents, even if you do it right.

Comment: I'll try paint event, thank you.